# Highcharts Timeline Renaming Series Labels

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts, timeline

I have this Highcharts timeline and I want to rename the series labels to be more descriptive (instead of displaying 'Series 1', 'Series 2', etc) in other words, a meaningful label name.

[image]

I thought it was as simple as adding brackets and calling the name property, but this fails to render.
This is troublesome, since this is the only documentation I can find on naming series in Highcharts.

Here is the code:

```
<script>
(function(H) {

  H.seriesTypes.timeline.prototype.getXExtremes = function(xData) {
    var series = this;

    return {
      min: H.arrayMin(xData),
      max: H.arrayMax(xData)
    };
  }
}(Highcharts));

Highcharts.dateFormats = {
  q: function(timestamp) {
    var date = new Date(timestamp),
      quarter = (Math.floor(date.getUTCMonth() / 3) + 1);
    return quarter;
  }
};
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    type: 'timeline'
  },
  //xAxis: {
  //type: 'datetime',
  //visible: true
  //},
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    units: [ // responsive ticks
      ['month', [3, 6]],
      ['year', [1]]
    ],
    labels: {
      format: '{value:Q%q\'%y}',
      //rotation: -30
    }
  },
  yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 1,
    title: null,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: true
  },
  title: {
    text: '<strong><font size="+10">INITIATIVE TIMELINE</font></strong>'
  },
  subtitle: {
    text: ''
  },
  tooltip: {
    style: {
      width: 300
    }
  },
  credits: {
    enabled: false
  },
  plotOptions: {
    timeline: {
      lineWidth: 0,
      legendType: '',
      showInLegend: true,
      colorByPoint: false,
      dataLabels: {
        allowOverlap: true,
        format: '<span style="color:{point.color}">● </span><span style="font-weight: bold;" > ' +
          '{point.x:%d %b %Y}</span><br/>{point.label}'
      },
      marker: {
        symbol: 'circle'
      },
    }
  },
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      distance: 40
    }, {name: 'TEST1',
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(1951, 5),
      name: 'First dogs in space',
      label: 'First dogs in space',
      description: "Dezik and Tsygan were the first dogs to make a sub-orbital flight on 22 July 1951. Both dogs were recovered unharmed after travelling to a maximum altitude of 110 km."
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(1971, 11, 2),
      name: 'First soft Mars landing',
      label: 'First soft Mars landing',
      description: "Mars 3 was an unmanned space probe of the Soviet Mars program which spanned the years between 1960 and 1973. Mars 3 was launched May 28, 1971, nine days after its twin spacecraft Mars 2. The probes were identical robotic spacecraft launched by Proton-K rockets with a Blok D upper stage, each consisting of an orbiter and an attached lander."
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(1976, 3, 17),
      name: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
      label: 'Closest flyby of the Sun',
      description: "Helios-A and Helios-B (also known as Helios 1 and Helios 2) are a pair of probes launched into heliocentric orbit for the purpose of studying solar processes. A joint venture of West Germany's space agency DFVLR (70 percent share) and NASA (30 percent), the probes were launched from Cape Canaveral Air Force Station, Florida."
    }]}
  }, {
    dataLabels: {
      distance: 90
    }, {name: 'TEST2',
    data: [{
      x: Date.UTC(1959, 0),
      name: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
      label: 'First artificial satellite to reach the Moon',
      description: "Luna 1 was the first artificial satellite to reach the Moon vicinity and first artificial satellite in heliocentric orbit."
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(1966, 1),
      name: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
      label: 'First soft landing on the Moon',
      description: "Yuri Gagarin was a Soviet pilot and cosmonaut. He became the first human to journey into outer space when his Vostok spacecraft completed one orbit of the Earth on 12 April 1961."
    }, {
      x: Date.UTC(1989, 7, 8),
      name: 'First astrometric satellite',
      label: 'First astrometric satellite',
      description: "Hipparcos was a scientific satellite of the European Space Agency (ESA), launched in 1989 and operated until 1993. It was the first space experiment devoted to precision astrometry, the accurate measurement of the positions of celestial objects on the sky."
    }]}
  }
});
</script>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, a few brackets were missing but the idea of adding name to a series is correct.
This property exists on the timeline series.

```js
  series: [{
    dataLabels: {
      distance: 40
    },
        name: 'TEST1',
    data: [{
```

**API:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.timeline.name
**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hxpqsndt/

Comment: Thanks, my syntax was wonky there. Works like a charm